# How do I add extended attributes to a folder I've created in Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox-api

I am building an app using Electron that uses Node js and the Dropbox javascript SDK to provide an interface between files store locally and on the users dropbox account.

One of the apps features is to be able to create a folder within the local Dropbox Desktop folder. I am doing this without any issues using the following code:

```
fs.mkdirSync(path_here);
```

but when I look at the local folder, it is set to not sync with Dropbox online. If I create a folder manually however, it sets to sync automatically without any problems ('Hello' is manual, 'Insight Manuals' is through Node JS):

[image]

On looking more closely through the command line I can see that it it likely due to the 'Hello' folder having extended attributes:

[image]

So now my question is, how can I add this extended attribute to the folder created through Node JS so it will sync as default like the manually created one?

Comment: can you try `ls -@` and check what are those attributes? or use `xattr -l Hello` to view them

Comment: @RyanWu That is what I used to display the second screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [fs-xattr](https://github.com/LinusU/fs-xattr) module.  This should allow you set whatever extended attributes you need.

Comment: The function to use is `xattr.set(path, attr, value, cb)` or `xattr.setSync(path, attr, value)`. To find what `value` should be, see the result of `xattr.getSync("./Hello", "com.dropbox.attributes")`.

Comment: Oh FAB! Thank you both! I shall take a look and report back! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I got the value of the com.dropbox.attributes xattr, assigned it to a variable and added it to the newly created folder using setSync and it all looks identical to Hello when I look at it on terminal now, but it's still isn't set to sync?! Any ideas where this approach might've gone wrong?

Comment: @HelenDangerBurns are you sure you're not suppose to create the folder via API? https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#fileops-create-folder, then your Dropbox folder will auto refresh to reflect this?

Comment: @dzm I see what you're saying but the idea is that the app controls what you have offline, like selective sync on Dropbox Desktop.... so this creating of a folder, isn't a new folder as such, it's a folder that exists on the online dropbox account that the users want available offline too... does that make sense?

Comment: @HelenDangerBurns I may not fully understand, but what is the difference in function between creating a folder with fs vs creating a "folder" in dropbox? When I create a folder in my Dropbox desktop, it syncs it to Dropbox, but the reverse is true if I create a folder in dropbox.com - essentially giving me the same result.

Comment: @dzm the folders in dropbox.com already exist and are controlled by someone else (it's a team folder). The idea of the app is to both online and offline access, with the user choosing which folders are available offline. The app deletes files and folders locally when the users sets them to 'online only' and creates the folders and downloads the files, mirroring the online structure, when the users sets them to 'available offline'.... so creating folders on dropbox.com isn't really the point, or a solution... does that help explain it a little better?

Comment: @dzm Regardless of this your answer was correct for the original question so I shall mark it so... but I would appreciate any further ideas you have on how to make this happen as I hope to?

Answer (score 0):

`com.dropbox.attributes` is added by Dropbox.

In this [document](https://www.dropbox.com/help/syncing-uploads/files-not-syncing), there're some files with incompatible characters in filename won't be sync on Windows

Try to trim the file name or just use simple name like `Hello2` to test it